# negating an expression in ebean

Tags: sql, playframework, playframework-2.3, ebean

I am using play framework 2.3.4 with ebean. I have these 2 tables in my database:

```
@Entity
public class Device extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "device")
    public List<DeviceInactivePeriod> inactivePeriods = new ArrayList<DeviceInactivePeriod>();

    ...
}

@Entity
public class DeviceInactivePeriod extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")
    public Date start;

    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")
    public Date end;

    @ManyToOne
    public Device device;

    ...

}
```

Imagine a `DeviceInactivePeriod` object as a time period, in which a device in INACTIVE. A `DEVICE` holds a list of them.

Now I want to query all devices, that in a specific moment(for example now) have no `DeviceInactivePeriod` (which means that the device is active)

I've tried many many many things, non worked. I have this query:

```
    Date now = new Date();
    return
            find.where().
                    and(
                        Expr.le("inactivePeriods.start", now),
                        Expr.ge("inactivePeriods.end", now)
                    )
                    .orderBy(sorting + " " + order)
                    .findPagingList(Global.PAGE_SIZE_DEVICES)
                    .setFetchAhead(false)
                    .getPage(page);
```

that returns exactly all devices that are INACTIVE. (opposite of what I want). Unfortunately negating this query does not return the result I expect. mayble I am negating wrong? here is what I do:

```
    Date now = new Date();
    return
            find.where().
                    .not(Expr.and(
                        Expr.le("inactivePeriods.start", now),
                        Expr.ge("inactivePeriods.end", now)
                    ))
                    .orderBy(sorting + " " + order)
                    .findPagingList(Global.PAGE_SIZE_DEVICES)
                    .setFetchAhead(false)
                    .getPage(page);
```

Can anyone suggest me a solution? Or can anyone suggest a raw SQL solution?

**UPDATE**

Here is the generated SQL :

`[debug] c.j.b.PreparedStatementHandle - select distinct t0.id c0, [...] from device t0 join device_inactive_period u1 on u1.device_id = t0.id  where not ((u1.start <= 2016-03-06 11:35:15.048  and u1.end >= 2016-03-06 11:35:15.048 ) )  order by t0.exp_date desc 
limit 11`

Problem is that for every `Device` there could be 0 to many lines in the `InactiveDevicePeriod` and SQL DBMS checks each row if `((u1.start <= 2016-03-06 11:35:15.048  and u1.end >= 2016-03-06 11:35:15.048 ) )` . for each device, if there exist only 1 row that returns true for this condition, this whole device will be returned. Other problem is, If a device has no `InactiveDevicePeriod` entry, it will not be returned.

In java it is equivalent to this peace of code(I think!)(in Device.java):

```
public boolean isActive_at_Wrong(Date date){
    for (DeviceInactivePeriod inactivePeriod : inactivePeriods) {
        if ( (inactivePeriod.start.before(date) || inactivePeriod.start.equals(date)) && inactivePeriod.end.after(date)){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But what I want is this(in Device.java):

```
public boolean isAactive_at_Correct(Date date){
    boolean active = true;
    for (DeviceInactivePeriod inactivePeriod : inactivePeriods) {
        if ( (inactivePeriod.start.before(date) || inactivePeriod.start.equals(date)) && inactivePeriod.end.after(date)){
            active = false;
        }
    }

    return active;
}
```

Comment: Include the generated SQL ... And then look at the where clause and describe what it needs to be, then post that up with your question.

Comment: I just updated the question with more info @RobBygrave

Answer (score 0):

I've did not tested it, but I think you can use a `between` clause instead:

```
Date now = new Date();
return find
    .where()
    .not(Expr.between("inactivePeriods.start", "inactivePeriods.end", now))
    .orderBy(sorting + " " + order)
    .findPagingList(Global.PAGE_SIZE_DEVICES)
    .setFetchAhead(false)
    .getPage(page);
```

Comment: thanks but it still does not return what I want. :-(

Comment: What is being returned in this case?

Comment: I have 4 sample devices, 2 are currently ACTIVE, and other 2 are currently INACTIVE. your code returns 1 of the actives and one of the in actives. the Inactive one that should not be returned, has the following `DeviceInactivePeriod` objects: 1) start: 9.2.2016 end: 1.3.2016 2) start: 3.3.2016 end: 6.3.2016

Comment: This is the generated SQL of your code ( I added the `[...]` myself)
`[debug] c.j.b.PreparedStatementHandle - select distinct t0.id c0, [...] from device t0 join device_inactive_period u1 on u1.device_id = t0.id  where not ( 2016-03-06 11:24:25.702  between u1.start and u1.end)  order by t0.exp_date desc 
limit 11`